# Java hide JFrame1 and JFrame2, when JFrame0 is deactivated?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

is there a way to hide all the other JFrames of my application, when the user clicks out of the "mainFrame"?

I tried with this

```
   public void windowActivated(WindowEvent we) {
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent we) {
        frame1.setVisible(false);
        frame2.setVisible(false);
    }`
```

but this doesn't work. All of my Windows start blinking. I cannot set JFrame2 unfocusable.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Are you using mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);?

Comment: Are you trying to minimize the JFrames or totally hide them?

Comment: I want to hide them like when I use setVisible(false). When I use mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); my application will be quit. I just want to hide the other windows.

Answer (score 2):

Use non-modal dialogs instead and the problem is sorted by default.

```
import javax.swing.*;

class TestDialogMinimize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Has a Dialog");

                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setSize(400,400);

                JDialog d = new JDialog(f);
                d.setSize(200,200);
                f.setVisible(true);
                d.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: (shrugs)  Sounds like it is not working now.  What is it about frames such that dialogs 'do not work' for your application?

Comment: It works for Windows, but not for Mac. Is there any other possibility?

Answer (score 1):

The non-modal dialog suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263104/java-hide-jframe1-and-jframe2-when-jframe0-is-deactivated/5263380#5263380) is one way to go.  See also [this answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449948/minimizing-a-supplementary-jframe-when-main-application-jframe-gets-minimized/3450435#3450435).

If for some reason you need to continue using frames, you can minify them with

```
frame1.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED)
```

and raise them with

```
frame1.setState(Frame.NORMAL)
```

Handle these in a code block like:

```
frame0.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
                // handle change
        }
    });
```

as described in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449948/minimizing-a-supplementary-jframe-when-main-application-jframe-gets-minimized).

If you want to close all frames when the frame0 is closed, you can use:

```
frame0.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

to exit the program and close all frames when the frame0 is closed. If you are just hiding on close use a window listener.  You can use `frame1.setVisible(false)` in your `WindowListener`.

Comment: I want all frames to hide, when the mainFrame is not activated (or probably focused?)… And all frames to show, when the mainFrame is activated (or probably not focused?)

Comment: @esanits - Use a [WindowFocusListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowFocusListener.html) and hide (as in `setVisible(false)`)on `windowLostFocus` and show (`setVisible(true)`) on `windowGainedFocus`.

Comment: I tried this, but when my mainFrame gains focus, the other windows will get visible and gain focus. Because of that will mainFrame lose focus and hide the other windows. Then it gains focus again (because the others are visible(false)) and all other windows will appear…

then my frames begin blinking…

btw, I am using Mac OS 10.6

Comment: @esanits - one way to fix this would be to implement a flag in your component that ignores the focusLost when you are in the middle of a transition.  Then have the main window get focus again with `frame0.requestFocus()`.  After that call is done set your flag to false.  Some sort of set of steps like that may aleviate the problem, but in general the problem of JFrames and focus is why usually there is only one frame in an app and everything else is a JDialog.

Comment: It also doesn't work with JDialogs for Mac OS X. The JDialogs will still be shown, when you click out of your mainFrame.